# How to jump to the next parameter / end of statement in Webstorm?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

I'm coming from an Eclipse background.

In Eclipse if you for example start to type a method invocation:

```
myObject.someMethod
```

Eclipse prefills the parameters like this:

```
myObject.someMethod(param1, param2)
```

and selects the first parameter. When you finished editing it you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to jump to the next param and after the last parameter pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> works like I've pressed <kbd>Home</kbd> and jumps to the end of the statement.

How can I achieve the same behavior in Webstorm? I'm really used to this feature so I miss it here. I tried the "Smart keys" but that feature is not **that** smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something similar in WebStorm, but it does not work exactly like Eclipse. In your example, you'd type

```
myObject.someMet
```

(or enough for WebStorm to find your function name) then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>. You would then see:

```
myObject.someMethod()
```

and your cursor will be in the parentheses.

You can then type the first parameter and when WebStorm has a suggestion you want to accept, you can **accept it by hitting comma**. WebStorm inserts your parameter value, and the comma following it. So this results in:

```
myObject.someMethod(param1, )
```

with your cursor in the right place to start typing your param2 value.

Incidentally, I found that the *Productivity Guide* (under the help menu) is a great way to find these sort of gems that you might be missing out on. Was really helpful when I switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ.

Comment: The point is that I wish to use the same key (no problem if it is not the **Enter**) key to jump through the parameters **and** to the end